# How to escape "<" character in regex in Solr schema.xml?

Tags: java, regex, solr

Using Solr 3.5.0 and in my schema.xml I'm using the following to mark the end of sentences and replace the end punctuation with a symbolic token:

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
pattern="(?<=[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?![']?\s|$)[^.!?]*)*)[.!?]+(?=\\s|$)"
replacement=" monkeysentence"/>
```

I'm not sure if that will even work for what I want, but first I need to solve the problem of escaping the '<' character in the first '?<=' lookbehind.

I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "pattern" 
associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

I've tried using a '\' as in:

```
 pattern="(?\<=[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?![']?\s|$)[^.!?]*)*)[.!?]+(?=\\s|$)"
```

But I get the same error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As this is in an XML file, you will need to use an XML escape to encode `<`, namely `&lt;` (you may also need to encode `>` as `&gt;`, `"` as `&quot;`, and `&` as `&amp;`)